# RFI on the amplifier due to Wifi

Tags: analog, noise, shielding

I have a board with a sensitive analog amplifier. This amplifier is optical in nature and it has a gain of 6M times.

On the same board there is a Wifi module. Somehow when Wifi is transmitting I see noise on my analog circuit.

I am sure it is not common mode noise. The only sensible explanation is RF energy getting into my circuit and being amplified.

How do I approach this problem? Shielding is the only option I can think of which I don't like to pursue. What other options I may have?

**UPDATE**
After several tests, I conclude the issue is RF signal to be shifting DC on the amplifier.

I use the following topology in my circuit:
[image]

What are the precautions I should take apart from the shielding to minimize the RFI problems? Adding RFI capacitors on inputs, modifying ground etc. I welcome expert advice.

Comment: More than likely you're seeing aliasing of the WIFI signal due to the multiplexing going on with the signal. I'd assume you can probably design a good low pass filter to remove signal. Even if it is aliased, the RF energy should still be in the high frequency domain and thus can be removed before amplification.

Comment: Is the supply rail really stable? A wifi module might draw 500 mW or 100 mA (peak) during transmit. Does your sensitive amplifier have its own regulator? And what path does the ground current from the WiFi take? Even the slightest board layout mistake will allow the WiFi current to couple into the input.

Comment: If it is really RF coupling in the front, you will be able to induce a similar problem by holding your prototype against the antenna of a router. Then unless your desired signal is in the GHz, you can start adding filters with discrete components.

Comment: @tomnexus I 100% confirm it is Rf causing the trouble. I use an external wifi module and reproduce the problem. Moreover after carefully checking I believe the ground of the analog board is acting as a receiver antenna and changing my ground and reference. The interfering signal is not at 2.4ghz but much lower reason is really the dc shift in my ground. I try to shield with limited success. No clue how to move forward now.

Comment: Ok. It's most likely coming in the front, but it could also be the power rails. If it's lower than 2.4 GHz, maybe a few kHz, then something in your circuit is rectifying the RF. Try putting a few pF between every signal input and ground, and keep the whole track for the cap shorter than 5 mm. All of your bypassing might be just too long to be effective at 2.4 GHz.

Comment: @tomnexus you are right. Something converting 2.4ghz rf to 1-3 MHz signal which is right in my measurement band. I experimented with 100pf capacitors which helped a bit but didn't solve the problem. I will continue to experiment. It seems that I would have to spin this board again. What other layout precautions I could take?

Comment: Can you move the WiFi antenna off the board? If not, at least make sure that it's not exciting the edge where your low voltage electronics lies... Some electromagnetic simulation required. Then make provision in your new layout for a very compact filter on the input(s), a series of 0402 pads for series and parallel components, a few in a row, so you can solder in any small filter you like, or bridge it out. Keep grounds short, several vias right next to each component.

Comment: Even if it was common mode noise, it would be a problem, because the amplifier input isn't a balanced line. If the noise is equally induced in the circuit around the inverting input and in the circuit around the noninverting input, those two will not cancel out due to differing impedances.

Comment: @Kaz indeed that's true. I kind of regret not building a differential amplifier for this circuit.  I doubt it is common noise because I filter everything to death and I cannot observe anything on the common mode signals.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the most likely culprit for a DC shift is the photo-diode itself. Depending on the lighting condition it will develop a bias. With indoor lighting 50Hz/60Hz flicker is likely, and there can be plenty of RF there too. Also the wifi-module probably has diodes (possibly blinking rapidly) which could be another source of noise. Try shielding the diode from light to see how that affects the situation. If it is the problem then consider changing the input connection or topology. You could bias the diode with a resistor and send the signal via a coupling capacitor, then you can adjust R and C to filter low-frequency components.

Comment: Unfortunately pd is not the problem. I observe the issue even when I remove the pd. the problem is really rfi rectification.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep my answer as I think it's relevant for others. I guess you should consider the board traces/wires, see if any of them act as a good antenna. If you have access to a scope that can see those frequencies, you could maybe probe them. Also, it might be helpful to know what part the amplifier is.